# android image loader sometime load wrong images or not load images

Tags: android

currently im working on android. i try to load a listview with some textviews and imageview. But, some imageviews of elements in listview does not show the correct picture. some imageviews of elements also not showing the picture, meanwhile in the web version all of those shows correctly. i check the url, and it's fine. so i guess the problem is in the image loader class. below is the image loader class(s) i use to show the pictures.

ImageLoader.java

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService; 

public ImageLoader(Context context){
    fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.no_picture_resize;
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    //System.out.println("URl = "+url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(100000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(100000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utility.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u;
        imageView=i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

}

FileCache.java

```
public class FileCache {

private File cacheDir;

public FileCache(Context context){
    //Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TempImages");
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

public File getFile(String url){
    String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;

}

public void clear(){
    File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
    if(files==null)
        return;
    for(File f:files)
        f.delete();
}
```

}

MemoryCache.java

```
public class MemoryCache {
private Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>());

public Bitmap get(String id){
    if(!cache.containsKey(id))
        return null;
    SoftReference<Bitmap> ref=cache.get(id);
    return ref.get();
}

public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
    cache.put(id, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
}

public void clear() {
    cache.clear();
}
```

}

I got those classes from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/. Please help As soon as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Try  [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for loading and caching images..

Comment: I highly recommend using a image loading framework such as Glide (https://github.com/bumptech/glide).
Correct dealing with images in ListViews can be fairly complex.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with recycling views as is done in a ListView, is occasionally requests to load an image aren't canceled when the ImageView is recycled. What happens is the ImageView loads the previous request instead of/over the current request, resulting in an incorrect image being displayed.

Instead of trying to create your own solution, you should go with one of the already-available libraries out there that deal with this particular nuance as well as a variety of other things (resizing to reduce memory, etc).

My current favorite is [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) (drop in), but other options are [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) (drop in) and [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) (complicated).